# Discord.js Music called from twitch bot issue finding voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My discord.js bot can play music when called within Discord itself, but I have a twitch bot also coded into the same instance. 
When calling the `play`command through twitch the bot crashes due to there being no channel info, Is there a way I can get a discord user ID's channel info, and have it join that channel instead of crashing due to the voice channel being undefined.

I've tried having the bot join the channel preemptively, tried `client.channel`.get, tried changing the `undefined` solving section in the libraries code, and I cannot find anything in the docs.

Snippet handling twitch interaction;

```
twitch_client.on('chat', (channel, user, message, self) => {
  if (message.startsWith('!play')) {
    song = message.replace(/!play /g, '');
    let channel = discord_client.channels.get('583035488655638528');
    discord_client.channels.get('573327430148947968').send('Sent from Twitch.');
    //channel.join()
    //.then(connection => console.log('Connected'))
    //.catch(console.error);
    discord_client.music.bot.playFunction(song);
  }
});
```

Discord handling portion is the default discord.js-musicbot-addon

Calls out

> \node_modules\discord.js-musicbot-addon\index.js:405
>         if (msg.member.voiceChannel === undefined) {
>                        ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'voiceChannel' of undefined
>       at Music.musicbot.playFunction (D:\Programming\DiscordTwitchBot\node_modules\discord.js-musicbot-addon\index.js:405:22)
>       at client. (D:\Programming\DiscordTwitchBot\index.js:36:30)
>       at client.EventEmitter.emit (D:\Programming\DiscordTwitchBot\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\events.js:101:25)
>       at client.EventEmitter.emits (D:\Programming\DiscordTwitchBot\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\events.js:64:19)
>       at client.handleMessage (D:\Programming\DiscordTwitchBot\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\client.js:992:34)
>       at D:\Programming\DiscordTwitchBot\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\client.js:1069:36
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at client._onMessage (D:\Programming\DiscordTwitchBot\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\client.js:1068:11)
>       at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\Programming\DiscordTwitchBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
>       at WebSocket.emit (events.js:200:13)

Answer (score 0):

In [`discord.js-musicbot-addon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-musicbot-addon)'s [`playFunction()`](https://github.com/DarkoPendragon/discord.js-musicbot-addon/blob/master/index.js#L404) function, the first parameter is the command message (from Discord), the second is the suffix/URL, and the third is the arguments. In your code, you're just passing `song`.

Comment: Oh, so in the 3rd argument, I could just pass the channel ID

Comment: Looking at the addon's code, it doesn't even appear that the third parameter is used in this function.

Comment: It seems like the only time args can be used is if its in an actual discord message, instead of being forced in playFunction()